# PHP: route URL to static pages/resources

Tags: php, design-patterns, url-routing

I am trying to figure out the best approach when linking to static pages using a loosely followed MVC design pattern.

I begin by rewriting all requests to the index.php which handles all request and break them down the url into the controller, action and parameters. However if i don't want to follow this url structure and just want to visit a static page such as 'http://example.com/home/' without having to call some action how would i achieve this without getting a php error caused by my router/dispatcher trying to request a file that does not exist?

I thought about setting up some switch statement or a if statement as shown below that checks if the url is set to something then uses a custom defined controller and action, or i wasn't sure whether to take the static resources out of the MVC directory and have it seperate and link to it that way?

```
<?php

class Router
{

    static public function parse($url, $request)
    {
        $url = trim($url);

        if ($url == "/")
        {
            $request->controller = "tasks";
            $request->action = "index";
            $request->params = [];
        }
        else
        {
            $explode_url = explode('/', $url);
            $explode_url = array_slice($explode_url, 2);
            $request->controller = $explode_url[0];
            $request->action = $explode_url[1];
            $request->params = array_slice($explode_url, 2);
        }

    }
}
?>
```

This works, but i'd rather not have a huge router setup for many different static resources as it feels tacky and that i am just patching together code. Would putting static pages in its own directory outside of MVC and linking to them in the views be a valid option? i'm relatively new to MVC so any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Your application shouldn't receive request it is not supposed to handle, you can solve this on a webserver level:
if you are using apache for example, you can setup in the .htaccess file that the request should be directed to your front controller (ex: index.php) only if the requested resource does not exist

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```